# Python web scraping using BeautifulSoup, how come my output file print out the contents three times with different format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I wanted to scrape statutes from this website:
http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0001/0001.html

I was able to write the output into a `txt` file, however, the output printed out three different formats as shown here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2l41o1eubutwanh/outflieFS.txt?dl=0

I am not good at formatting output. Could it be something wrong with my `write` statement, or where am I doing wrong?

my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

f = open('C:\Python27\projects\outflieFS.txt','w')

def First_part(url):
  thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,'html.parser')
  return soupdata


soup = First_part("http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0002/0002.html")

tableContents = soup.find('div', {'id': 'statutes' })

for data in tableContents.findAll('div'):
  data = data.text.encode("utf-8","ignore")
  data = str(data)+ "\n\n"
  f.write(data)

f.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post your output as an image :)

Comment: My bad, I changed it to a dropbox link

Comment: What do you want the output format to look like?

Comment: I want my ouput format look like the one display on the cite, with sentence/paragraph breaks.  The closest one I got is the last format in my txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain what is happening, so you can work that out: when you call the find_all, you planify the hierarchical structure of the div in the content. So, if you have 3 levels of div, you will have 3 items as a result of your find_all and your result (I did not have access to your dropbox, so I didnt saw it) should look like this:

```
div div div content
div div same content
div same content again
```

So, the solution is to identify the class or id of the inner most div and use it on the find_all to get only one level, the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Write recursive=False as an argument in find_all. The find_all method defaults to an examination of all the descendants of the tag (e.g. 'div'), which is causing repetition in your results. The line will look like this:

`for data in tableContents.findAll('div', recursive=False):`

find_all will now examine the direct descendants only, i.e. the tags directly beneath 'div'. It will not find the tags nested inside those tags.

The consequence of this is that find_all will only return results that are the direct children of the tag which has been specified in the parentheses.